# Dynamically fill multiple input fields from MySQL depending on the drop list item selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've searched through the site for this but am coming up empty handed. Here is what I am trying to do:

- User selects one of a series of options from a drop list
- Two input fields change to reflect this selection, filling the input boxes with data pulled from my database

*See the image below for a visual representation of what I mean:*
[image]

I know that I am going to need JavaScript for this solution, but my JS skills are not so hot (and I think I am having a momentary lapse of brain power today)!

Here's the code that I have so far (don't worry about the outdated PHP):

```
<select name="item" id="item">

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $item_id = $row['item_id'];
    $item_category = $row['item_category'];
    $item_title = $row['item_title'];
    $item_price = $row['item_price'];
    $item_description = $row['item_description'];

    echo "<option value=\"".$item_id."\">".$item_title."</option>";
} 
?>

</select>

<script>
function update_txt() {
    price = document.getElementById('item').selectedIndex.value;
    document.getElementById('item_details').value = price;
    document.getElementById('item_price').value = price;
}
</script>

<input id="item_details" type="text" class="validate">
<input id="item_price" type="text" class="validate" value="$">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any clarification. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would json encode the row and store it as a data-attribute on the option, then read the attribute on the selects change event:

```
<select name="item" id="item">
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $item_id = $row['item_id'];
        $item_title = $row['item_title'];
        echo "<option value=\"".$item_id."\" data-json='" . json_encode($row) . "'>".$item_title."</option>";
    } 
 ?>
</select>
<input id="item_details" type="text" class="validate">
<input id="item_price" type="text" class="validate" value="$">

<script>
    $('#item').on('change', function() {
        var selected = $(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('json');
        $('#item_details').val(selected.item_description);
        $('#item_price').val(selected.item_price);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, data-attributes! Thanks for this! I hadn't been aware of this ability. That sounds like it will work perfectly. :)

Comment: How should this be modified if `$row` is obtained via a combination of `$result = $conn->query($sql);` and `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()` ? The format of the resulting json differs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of PHP, AJAX and JavaScript (or jQuery).

The general idea is as follows:

1. User selects an option(s)
2. JavaScript is used to detect the selection and the option(s)
   selected
3. AJAX gets the options selected, formats it and passes it to a PHP "page"
4. PHP does the SQL queries and passes the values back
5. AJAX gets those values and populates the current page using standard JavaScript methods

There's a good tutorial here which shows how it fits together:  http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php.  I would use prepared statements instead of the SQL queries shown in this example though.